# PIL: Load image on <img> tag in Flask

Tags: html, image, flask, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I am getting an image file "plot.png" from s3 bucket using the following code

```
def read_froms3img(image_name):
    ep_url=URL
    access_id=ID_KEY
    access_key=SECRET_KEY
    
    s3_resource = boto3.resource(service_name = "s3",endpoint_url=ep_url,  aws_access_key_id=access_id,   aws_secret_access_key=access_key)
    s3_client = boto3.client(service_name = "s3",endpoint_url=ep_url,  aws_access_key_id=access_id ,   aws_secret_access_key=access_key)

    bucket = s3_bucket
    bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket)
    image = bucket.Object('Images/plot.png')
    img_data = image.get().get('Body').read()

    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))
```

I am calling the above function as below and pass the "contents" to the render_template('data.html)

```
contents = read_froms3img("plot.png")

return render_template('data.html', form_data = form_data, html_code = html, filename = contents)
```

And if i do **contents.show()**, it loads the image in my local.

**data.html:**

```
<img src="{{filename}}" height="50%" width="65%">
```

But the image is not loading in the frontend, if i do inspect element, i can see the below code in the  tag

```
<img src="<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=640x480 at 0x257583E0DF0>" height="50%" width="65%">
```

How to display the image in the  tag in the html page.

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I think you want to allow the web-browser to view an image stored in an S3 bucket. So, make your HTML point to a Flask view like this:

```
<img src="/S3image/REFERENCE">
```

where REFERENCE is something that uniquely identifies an image on your S3. Then in your Flask app:

```
from flask import Response

@app.route('/S3image/<ref>')
def serveS3(ref):
    ...
    ... all your code except your 'return' statement
    ...
    return Response(img_data, mimetype='image/png')
```

**Original Answer**

You can't return a Python `PIL Image` object to a web-browser... they don't understand Python. You need to return a PNG image, and you have one already in your variable `img_data`, so just return that with the appropriate MIME type.

It will look something like:

```
from flask import Response

....
....
return Response(img_data, mimetype='image/png')
```

Comment: so i should do this line of code in render_template() and how to call it in <img>.. can u please help here

Comment: I can't tell from your code what's best for your situation. If you just have one image on S3 and you want the browser to be able to see it, you could grab the data from S3 and write it to a file on your server `with open('fileXXX.PNG', 'wb') as f: f.write(img_data)` anf put `fileXXX.png` in the `<img src="fileXXX.png">`. If you have lots of images you might put a route+view in your Flask that takes a parameter and returns a PNG like my answer suggests.

Comment: To answer your question *"What do I put in the `<image>` tag in the HTML?"* differently... you can either save the image from S3 into a file on your webserver and put the filename in the tag. Or, you can put a route to a Flask function, say `/S3image/<ref>` where `ref` is a reference to your S3 bucket, and return a PNG like my answer suggests.

Comment: is this what u meant


@app.route("/s3image/<ref>")
def contents():
    return read_froms3img("plot.png")
 
===============
in html: 
<img src="{{url_for('s3image', ref="plot.png")}}" height="50%" width="65%">

Comment: Nearly - have a look at my updated answer which is easier to read than unformatted comments.

Comment: Any luck/progress with this?